# elixir coverex getting function :cover.start/0 is undefined (module :cover is not available)

Tags: testing, elixir

I have added the coverage_tool key to the project def and added coverex to the deps defp, and performed a mix deps.get.

But, when I run 'mix test --cover' it gives me 
'function :cover.start/0 is undefined (module :cover is not available)'

Comment: Could you find it by ` mix deps | grep cover`?

Comment: Look like [this issue](https://github.com/alfert/coverex/issues/29).